# printf with relational signs

Tags: c, printf, relational

```
int i = 5, j = 10, k = 1;  
printf("%d\n", k > i < j);
```

Why does it print out 1?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully it would print nothing at all, as something as confusing as that should be illegal. However, if we absolutely have to do it:

`k > i < j` would be broken down into two parts: `k > i`, then the result of that is compared to `j`. The result of a comparison like this is 1 if `true` or 0 if `false`. Since `k > i` is `false`, we get 0; then `0 < j` is `true` so we get 1. Therefore, this will print 1.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out in what order the operations are evaluated. Use associativity column from [this table](http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_operators.html) for help. Next, figure out what is the value of `k > i`. Use `printf` to try it out. Finally, figure out the value of the last expression, and run the program to see if your answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you the table helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`k > i < j` is an expression, and it will be evaluated completely before `printf` is even called; all `printf` will see is the result of the evaluation. As for what it evaluates to, the operators are simply evaluated individually from right to left; so `k > i` will be evaluated first, followed by the result of that applied to `<` with `j` on the right hand side.

Note that this might go differently if we had operators other than `<` and `>`; those just happen to have the same level of precedence, so they are always evaluated from left to right. If, on the other hand, we had `k + i * j`, `i * j` would be evaluated first. This is because `*` has a higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: So can I assume that it either returns 0 or 1 because it's only a true/false evaluation?

Comment: @ChuhanFrankQin, Yes, both `<` and `>` always return either a 0 or a 1, since they are boolean operators.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now realize how stupid my question was..

Comment: @ChuhanFrankQin, No problem! We have to crawl before we can run.